# Opening .dat files in C

Tags: c

I am a novice programmer and just had a question regarding the opening of .dat files in C.

I received a .dat file from a friend, and these were the instructions on how to open it:

> The first 4 bytes contain an integer
>   number that indicates how many
>   subsequent bytes you can throw away.
>   The byte after that contains the ASCII
>   code for a single letter in the
>   message. The next 4 bytes contain the
>   number of junk bytes that you can
>   throw away, and then read the next
>   letter, etc.  The last byte in the
>   file will be the last letter in the
>   message.

I'm really just looking for a way to view individual bytes of the file; at this point I'm fairly confused...

Comment: why can't your "friend" use email?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`fread()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fread) to read bytes from the file and [`fseek()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fseek) to seek to a different position (e.g. to "throw away bytes").

However, to parse the first number you need to know the endianness of the file unless they are actually 4 ascii characters representing digits; in that case you could use `atoi()` to get the number.

Here's some example code:

```
unsigned char buf[4];
FILE *fp = fopen("test.dat", "rb");
while(!feof(fp)) {
    fread(buf, 4, 1, fp); // read 4 bytes
    int throw_away = do_some_magic_to_get_the_number(buf);
    fseek(fp, throw_away, SEEK_CUR); // skip the given number of bytes
    fread(buf, 1, 1, fp); // read one byte
    // your character is now in buf[0]
}
```

Comment: Virtually all use of `while (!feof(fp))` is wrong (including this one).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're reading this on the same type of machine as it was written on (i.e. both are big-endian or both are little-endian), I'd probably write the code something like this:

```
uint32_t skip;

while (fread(&skip, sizeof(skip), 1, infile)) {
    fseek(infile, skip, SEEK_CUR);
    putchar(fgetc(infile));
}
```

If you need to deal with endianess issues, I'd probably use `htonl` on the data before writing, and `ntohl` on it after reading. There are, however, *lots* of alternatives -- XDR and ASN.1 (to name only a couple) were intended for jobs like this (though, I should add that both of those are almost certainly overkill for the task at hand).

Answer (score -1):

Check out [this](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/cfileio.html) documentation for how the file operations work.

```
unsigned char input buf[4]; 
FILE *fp = fopen("test.dat", "rb"); 
while(!feof(fp)) {   
  fread(buf, 4, 1, fp);   
  int skip_num = (int)buf; // should be able to cast since 4bytes = 1int and we have been told that this is an int.   
  for( ; skip_num >= 0; skip_num--) {}   
  fread(buf, 1, 1, fp); // This is the actual character do something with buf[0]. 
}
```

Comment: Your use of `while (!feof(fp))` is buggy.